# UDP recvfrom() causing issues

Tags: c++, visual-studio, networking, udp

I have been trying to receive a data packet from a client however during the recvfrom() process I think im doing something wrong...

I have whats named a DataPacket and its just a class with some x & y values

The Client does the following...

```
int UDPCon::Send(DataPacket dPacket)
{
    int n = sendto(m_Socket,  (char *)&dPacket, PACKETSIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&m_RemoteAddress, m_SocketAddressSize);   
    return n;   
}
```

And the server receives

```
int CUDPSocket::Receive(DataPacket *data)
{
    int n = recvfrom(m_Socket, (char *) &data, PACKETSIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&m_RemoteAddress, &m_SocketAddressSize);
    return n;
}
```

This used to work when I was simply sending char's without the casting back so the code did work. I think im doing something wrong with the pointer, as soon as the recvfrom() has put the data into "data" the DataPacket "data" becomes "expression cannot be evaluated"

I would really appreciate any help

Thanks

Comment: DataPacket is a class with int x, y; thats pretty much it. This did work before it was in a class, the only difference is I pass a pointer through so the value gets edited.

Comment: Well, how is that class related to the PACKETSIZE ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're sending a struct, or at least the raw data in a `DataPacket`. In that case, change the server code to

```
int CUDPSocket::Receive(DataPacket *data)
{
    int n = recvfrom(m_Socket, (char *) data, PACKETSIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&m_RemoteAddress, &m_SocketAddressSize);
    return n;
}
```

Though, you should show the declaration of DataPacket and PACKETSIZE  , the above might or might not do what you need to do.

Comment: thanks a lot, I figured I was doing something stupid with the pointer =)

Answer (score 1):

Your `Receive` function takes in a pointer to a DataPacket.  But when you call `recvfrom` you're passing `(char*) &data` which is a *pointer to a pointer*.  That means you're writing the packet data overtop of the *pointer* rather than into it.

The fix is simple, call `recvfrom` with `(char*)data` so that `recvfrom` writes into the DataPacket rather than overtop of the DataPacket pointer.

Answer (score 1):

In the receiver `data` is already a pointer so your use of `&` address-of operator is a mistake (the result of that expression be the address of the pointer).

Simply changing the receiver call to

```
int n = recvfrom(m_socket, (char *)data, ... );
```

will solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In your call you are passing the address of the pointer data to recvfrom, so recvfrom is writing to the memory where the pointer variable data is stored. You need to pass "(char *) data" instead of "(char *) &data".